# Instagram public pages feed Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I need to get the public posts for public pages in Instagram using graph API. If I granted the instagram basics and Instagram public content access requests. It will be enough to enter page ID for the graph API to retrieve the media of the page? From the graph API documentation I can see that I can only use the instagram user ID. Is it the same in case of public pages?
Something like below to retrieve media list and number of followers?

```
GET /v3.3/{instagram-page-id}?fields=media,followed_by_count
```

Comment: "something like xy" - so what happens if you try it?

Comment: In order to try it I have to apply on Instagram public content access. I already applied and I'm moving forward with the process. I need to know if this is going to work or not.

Comment: you should be able to try with your own account, afaik

Comment: I tried but still receiving error from graph API"Unsupported get request. Object with ID '922296214' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"